# Delete duplicate rows and sum corresponding values of last column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

If we want to remove the duplicates from a dataframe `df`, we need just to write `df[!duplicated(df),]` and duplicates will be removed from it. I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(from = c("z","y","z","w","y"), to=c("x","w","x","z","w"), weight=c(2,1,3,5,6))
```

I would like to obtain something different. In `df[,1:2]`, the first and the third rows are equals between them and I would like to: 1) delete one of them; 2) sum the corresponding values of weight. E.g. for this example, the expected result is:

```
   from to weight
     z  x      5
     y  w      7
     w  z      5
```

Anyway, if I use:

```
df2=df[,1:2]
which(duplicated(df2) | duplicated(df2[nrow(df2):1, ])[nrow(df2):1])
```

I obtain

```
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

which does not allow me to obtain the desidered result (e.g. 1 and 3 are equals between them, 2 and 5 are equals between them, but this information is not contained in the latter result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by `sum`operation instead of `duplicated`

```
aggregate(weight~ ., df, sum)
```

---

In `dplyr`, this can be done using

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(from, to) %>%
   summarise(weight = sum(weight))
```